# Best alternative for "web essentials" extension for visual studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, web, visual-studio-extensions

unfortunately "web essential" extension developers didn't roll out new version that works with visual studio 2022 and the last version is only compatible with VS 2019. what do you recommend instead??

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a replacement extension, maybe you can [ask the author](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2019/issues) when will update it

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the [Web Compiler 2022+ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64), which is a version forked from Mads' original extension. It has been done with permission ([see github thread discussion](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/566)).

This will allow the use of the now [deprecated node sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) instead of dart sass.